# Why the asterisk (*) wildcard is not evaluated in these two cases?

Tags: linux, bash

If I have this command:

```
expr 2 * 4
```

It will not work, because the `*` wildcard will be evaluated, and so I have to escape it:

```
expr 2 \* 4
```

---

But if I have the following two cases:

```
let var1=2*4

var2=$((2*4))
```

Then the `*` wildcard will not be evaluated, and so there is no need to escape it.

Why the `*` wildcard did not get evaluated in the above two cases? my guess is that `bash` simply does not evaluate it when using `let` and `$(())`.

If this is the case, are there other situations where wildcards do not get evaluated?

Comment: the whitespace around the '*' caused it to be evaluated differently

Answer (score 1):

In `var2=2*4`, because of spaces (metacharacters), and that there is no file starting with a `2`, some characters, and a 4 in the pwd.

The line is split in tokens using spaces as delimiters.

This has no spaces (and after the `=` it is considered quoted):

```
$ var1=2*4
```

But this does:

```
$ echo 2 * 4
```

And the `*` becomes a token and is expanded (as a filename expansion).

To avoid the special effect of `*` use quoting:

```
$ expr 2 \* 4
8
$ expr 2 "*" 4
8
$ expr 2 '*' 4
8
```

However, this does expand:

```
$ touch 2good4
$ echo 2*4
2good4
```

In `echo $((2*4))`, what is inside a `$((…))` construct is interpreted as an arithmetic expansion. any of this will do the same (even with the spaces):

```
$ echo $((2*4))
8
$ echo $(( 2 * 4 ))
8
$ echo $((    2   *    4    ))
8
```

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you see is explained [here for globbing](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/globs) and [here for expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/SpecialCharacters) and the `man let` page for the parameter specification bash knows to give to 'let'

When bash sees `*` on it's own it performs pathname expansion **except**
where the expansion returns a null result in which case it returns the literal string.

```
echo 2 * 4     #echo 2, the contents of the pwd and then 4
```

If `*` is preceded by a marker that tells it to use a difference form or expansion (math/command/parameter or no expansion at all) then it uses the relevant method. So

```
let var1=2*4   #pass the **arithmetic** argument var1=2*4 to the let command because bash knows let takes special characters (% * etc) as arguments

var2=$((2*4))  #bash parses the string as far as $ and sees an instruction to expand
               #bash then sees (( the which specifies arithmetic expansion specifies
```

and as you said

```
echo 2 \* 4   #perform no expansion
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the reason, you should know what can * do in bash and how bash parse commands:

first, what can * do in bash:

1. as a wild card in file name glob
2. multiply
3. 0 or more times in regex

   ...

and how bash parse commands (greatly simplified, it's very complicated actually):

1. parameter substitution
2. command substitution
3. globbing

   ...

Suppose you hava **a.txt b.txt** in current directory, in `expr 2 * 4`, after parameter substitution -> command substitution
-> globbing, it will become

```
expr 2 a.txt b.txt 4
```

which of cause will not return the right answer.

However in `expr 2 \* 4`, * is a character! None of parameter substitution, command substitution, globbing will affect it. so expr get 3 parameters 2 * 4, and it will return 8.

In `let var1=2*4`, bash make an arithmetic substitution before globing, the command after pasing is `let var1=8`. If you have 2a4 2b4 in current directory and you dont't use let, just

```
var1=2*4
echo $var1
```

It will return 2a4 2b4, NOT 8.

In `var2=$((2*4))`, bash make an arithmetic substitution too because (()) is arithmetic operator.

**PS:** If you want * be an arithmetic operator, keep it in (()) $[] or using let,eg:

```
((var1 = 2 * 4)) or var1=$((2 * 4))
var1=$[2 * 4]
```

WHITESPACES are allowed！